# If No File is Submitted Set SQL Column to NULL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, forms

I am trying to make a form where the user can submit 5 images. The image's names that are submitted get saved to my MSSQL table columns photo, photo1, photo2, photo3, and photo4. The columns are all in the same table `new_trailers1`. If the user only uploads images in first three inputs and leaves the last two inputs, the columns should be set as photo=`image.jpg` photo1=`image2.jpg` photo2=`image3.jpg` photo3=`NULL` and photo4=`NULL`. Currently, the images are being saved as empty instead of NULL. For example, the column for photo3 is set to .  Here is what I have for my PHP code when the user submits the form:

```
    if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    // Make sure the file was sent without errors
    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {

    // Connect to the database
    $conn = mssql_connect('gace.com','user','pass');
    mssql_select_db('ger',$conn);

        // Gather all required data

        //IMAGES

        //This is the directory where images will be saved 
         $target = "unitimages/"; 
         $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
         $target1 = "unitimages/"; 
         $target1 = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name']);
         $target2 = "unitimages/"; 
         $target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name']);
         $target3 = "unitimages/"; 
         $target3 = $target3 . basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name']);
         $target4 = "unitimages/"; 
         $target4 = $target4 . basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name']); 
         // Where PDF is saved
         $target5 = "unitimages/"; 
         $target5 = $target5 . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

          $pic1=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
           $pic2=($_FILES['photo1']['name']); 
            $pic3=($_FILES['photo2']['name']); 
             $pic4=($_FILES['photo3']['name']); 
              $pic5=($_FILES['photo4']['name']);
               $name=($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);  

         if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
        {
            $title = addslashes ($_POST['title']);
            $desc = addslashes ($_POST['description']);
            $make = addslashes ($_POST['make']);
            $model = addslashes ($_POST['model']);
            $year = addslashes ($_POST['year']);
            $price = addslashes ($_POST['price']);
        }
        else
        {
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $desc = $_POST['description'];
            $make = $_POST['make'];
            $model = $_POST['model'];
            $year = $_POST['year'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];
}

   $columnid_query=mssql_query("SELECT MAX(orderid) FROM new_trailers1", $conn);
   $columnid_array=mssql_fetch_row($columnid_query);
   $newcolumnid=$columnid_array[0]+1;

        // Create the SQL query
$query = ("INSERT INTO new_trailers1 (title, orderid, description, make, model, year, price, name, photo, photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4) VALUES ('$title', '$newcolumnid', '$desc', '$make', '$model', '$year', '$price', '$name', '$pic1', '$pic2', '$pic3', '$pic4', '$pic5')") ; 

        // Execute the query
   $result = mssql_query($query, $conn) or die(mssql_get_last_message());

        // Check if it was successfull
        if($result) {
           $updater = "UPDATE new_trailers1 SET (photo=NULL, photo1=NULL, photo2=NULL, photo3=NULL, photo4=NULL) WHERE (photo='',photo1='',photo2='',photo3='',photo4='')";
           $updateda = mssql_query($updater, $conn) or die(mssql_get_last_message());
           if($updateda) { echo'<script>
alert("Suasd added successfully!");
</script>'; }
            echo '<script>
alert("Success! New Unit was added successfully!");
</script>';
        echo '<script>window.location.replace("newunitsmanagement.php");</script>';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
               . "<pre>{$conn->error}</pre>";
        }

//Writes the photos to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 //echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 }
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target1)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
// echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 //echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 } 
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'], $target2)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 //echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 } 
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name'], $target3)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 //echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 } 
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo4']['tmp_name'], $target4)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 //echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 }

 //Writes the PDF to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target5)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 //echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your image."; 
 }

    }
    else {
        echo '<div class="errormess"> '
           . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']). '</div>';
               echo '<script>
alert("A file for PDF Specs must be chosen. If a file for PDF Specs was chosen, see error code at the bottom of the page.");
</script>';
    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    //$conn->close();
}


else {
    //echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}
```

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Comment: remove username and password to your database!!

Comment: delete this question and change your username and password ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MSSQL as the tags suggest, then:

```
UPDATE new_trailers1 SET (photo=NULL, photo1=NULL, photo2=NULL, photo3=NULL, photo4=NULL) WHERE (photo='',photo1='',photo2='',photo3='',photo4='')
```

Should be

```
UPDATE new_trailers1 SET photo=NULL, photo1=NULL, photo2=NULL, photo3=NULL, photo4=NULL WHERE photo='' AND photo1='' AND photo2='' AND photo3='' AND photo4=''
```

This will only update where all photos are blank though.  So if you want to update each field based on each fields unique value, you need to issue four separate update statements, one for each photo field.

Comment: Do I get an up-vote for the help, Michael?  A bit of thanks goes a long way :)

Answer (score 0):

I think You can solve it from your database settings.
Try to go to your SQL table, click "Structure" then edit and set NULL as default in the required fields.

Comment: I don't have access to the cPanel, so I would have to alter the table through PHP. When I made my table, I used the PHP code `photo varchar(150) null,` to create the `photo` column when I created the table. What PHP code would I have to use to alter the column to make it's default set to NULL?